# Changing Switch value dynamically

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying build a product list and change the product status dynamically, but when I click a switch and so other and back to click the first one, it is changing the both values at same time in firebase and in app. How I can fix this problem?

**My ProductsFragment class:**

```
public class ProductsFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_product);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        //Setting adapter and Holder
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_product_list, parent, false);
                return new ProductHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductHolder holder, final int position,
                                            @NonNull final Product model) {
                    holder.mAvailableSwitch.setChecked(model.isAvailable());
                    holder.mAvailableSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                                    updateStatus(model, b);
                                }
                            });
            }

            //Update product status
            public void updateStatus(Product product,
                                     boolean available) {

                String key = product.getUid();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put(FirebaseUtils.getProductsPath() + key + "/available",
                        available); 
                mBaseRef = FirebaseUtils.getBaseRef();
                mBaseRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
        }
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Switch mAvailableSwitch;
        public ProductHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            mAvailableSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.product_available);
        }
    }
```

**item_product_list.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <Switch
           android:id="@+id/product_available"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: whats the actual problem ?? you want to change it in different tym ??

Comment: Is crashing with what error and at which line?

Comment: For example: I have 4 product and so a switch the first after the second and back to switch the fisrt, the app changes both switch at some time.

Answer (score 0):

solved!
Just add addOnSuccessListener or a addOnCompletedListener on the call of updateChildren() and call the method notifyItemChaged();

Example with firestore:

```
holder.mAvailableSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean b) {
                DocumentReference productRef =
                        new FirebaseUtils().productRef().document(model.getUid());
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("available", b);
                Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + model.getUid());

                productRef.update(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        model.setAvailable(b);
                        notifyItemChanged(position, model);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```